# Name for bounded piecewise linear function?

Tags: functions, notation

Is there a name for the bounded piecewise linear function

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
x,& x\in [-1,1] \\
-1,& x < -1, \\
1,& x > 1.
\end{cases} $$

It resembles the tanh function but does not have continuous derivatives.

Comment: On what reason the question should be closed? It’s just a valid question by a newby.

Comment: It is not a "linear function" in any conventional sense, although it is a *piecewise llinear* continuous function (first-degree spline).  It more closely resembles the (discontinuous) "signum" function $$\operatorname{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{when } x \gt 0 \\ 0 &\text{when } x = 0 \\ -1 &\text{when } x\lt 0 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a ramped step function.

You may express $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x,& x\in [-1,1] \\
-1,& x < -1, \\
1,& x > 1.
\end{cases}$$

as a heaviside function.

On the positive reals your function is $$f(t)=t-(t-1)H(t-1)$$ and on the negative reals it is $$g(t)=-f(-t).$$

Comment: Doesn’t provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I see that f(x) = max(0,x) is called the "ramp" function in Wikedia. The reason I asked the question is that I want to define the function in some computer code and wanted to know what to name it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have seen ramp function used before.

Answer (score 0):

In the deep learning (artificial neural networks) literature, the function is known as the "hard tanh" function. In their course notes https://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/LectureNotes3.pdf for "CS 224D: Deep Learning for NLP", Rohit Mundra and Richard Socher state that "The hard tanh function is sometimes preferred over the tanh function [as an activation function for neural networks] since it is computationally cheaper."